# I want to get and display items name from list in a list of Category widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, arraylist

I want to get and display items name from list in a list of Category widgets
when user click on category name I should get items and display it under category name as in image.

So, I want to add items to List of String in a larger List
I tried alot in initiation the List and tried alot in adding or assigning value one by one but i faild to do it.

I am asking how to declare initiate and use variable List<List< String>>, thats all, or if there is another way to have List for each category.

[image]

[image]

this is a simple code:

```
    List<List<String>> itemsList = [[]];
    Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: itemsCategories.length ,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap:() async{
        List<String> tempList = await getItems();
                        // add to list of list
        for (var element in temp) {  itemsList [index].add(element);  }

                      print( 'tempList[index] items: ${tempList[index]}');
                    }
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextitemsCategories[index].name),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
     ),
    )
```

I tried another way to assign data to list

```
// assign value one by one
for (var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
itemsList[index][i]= tempList [i];
print( itemsList[index][i]);
}
```

I got different errors like
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter ( 8581): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
E/flutter ( 8581): #1      _HomeState.build..

Comment: Add you complete code, unable to understand `temptempList` and `itemsCategories`

Comment: The code is too big and complicated, I am asking how to declare initiate and use variable List<List<String>>, thats all, or if there is another way to have List<String> for each category.

Comment: I don't think you will need a List<List<String>. To show the category name probably what you want is a List<Category>, where Category is a class that has a property List<String> called "items". Then you use ListView.builder to iterate through the list of categories and inside it use the items property for each iteration

Comment: Thank you Samuel, this is the easy and simple way, the items is not property in categories, but still it is easier to make a separate class with list property, I thought the list of list is easy variable to use but it takes hours to understand and use it, and failed at the end :(